# JavaScript - Trigger Twitter intent "follow" callback only if user actually follows

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-oauth

**Product I am working on:** Requestly - Chrome and Firefox Extension Setup redirects, modify headers, switch hosts, insert user scripts (https://www.requestly.in/)

**What I am trying to do:** Requestly offers free 30 days access to GOLD Plan if user completes a set of few steps. One of such steps is to follow us on Twitter. I want to verify if the user has actually followed us on Twitter.

```
 //After loading widgets.js    
    function followIntent (intentEvent) { 
        console.log("User Followed")
    };    
    twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
      twttr.events.bind('follow', followIntent);
    });
```

**Problem:** The "followIntent" function is getting triggered as soon as user clicks the Follow button. I want it to be called only after user has successfully followed us. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Bind is to apply the function binding is it ?? the syntax would be fn.bind(null, 'follow', callback). Here null is context.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running into a problem that the `follow` event occurs in between the events of user clicking the "following" button and the actual "following" happens. You can always call the Twitter API to verify it via `GET followers/ids`. Though it seems a bit unnecessary...

```
function followIntent (intentEvent) { 
  if (!intentEvent) return;
  followerVerification(intentEvent.data.user_id);
};

async function followerVerification (userID) {
  // make your API request here
  var userList = await twitterAPIRequest();
  if (userList.includes(userID)){
    console.log("User Followed")
  } else {
    console.log("User Not Followed")
  }
}

function twitterAPIRequest() {
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "url": "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?screen_name=twitterdev",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      // Your app autherization stuff
    }
  }

  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    return response.ids;
  });
}

twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
  twttr.events.bind('follow', followIntent);
});
```